# Running powershell script from aspx page permission issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, permissions

I'm trying to run a powershell script from aspx page.  I looked and googled around and found this piece of code [from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2008/07/26/calling-a-powershell-script-from-your-net-code.aspx) named `private string RunScript(string scriptText) (c# version)` .  The problem is that I'm getting permission issues when I run the script using Visual Studio 2010.  I tried running VS as an administrator but I got the same problem.

What the aspx page does is it actually writes a powershell script and passes the string to `scriptText`.  I confirmed that if I put the powershell lines in a file and run it on the command line it works.

Here's a sample of my powershell script that the aspx generates and tries to execute when a page is requested (using openxml powertools to merge pptx documents).

```
Import-Module Oxpt
$pml0 = New-PmlDocument "c:\MergeTemp\0.pptx"
$pres0 = New-Object OpenXmlPowerTools.SlideSource($pml0, $false )
$pml1 = New-PmlDocument "c:\MergeTemp\1.pptx"
$pres1 = New-Object OpenXmlPowerTools.SlideSource($pml1, $false )

$sources = ($pres0, $pres1)
Merge-Pptx -OutputPath c:\SlideMergeTemp\out.pptx -Sources $sources
```

If I place `Set-ExecutionPolicy` I get `access to registry is denied`.  If I `scope` it to `CurrentUser` or `LocalMachine` I get error saying `AuthorizationManager Check Failed`.

How can I make this work?  At some point I have to release this into production.  What would be the correct permission to run the powershell script through the code using aspx page?

Comment: `Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();` is where it throws exception (just to clarify)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but have you fiddled with the System.Management.Automation Powershell class (instead of going through Runspace) ? I rememember it saving me a lot of trouble last time I wanted to call powershell code from C#.

Comment: @PhilGref Thanks Phil. If I'm not mistaking the reference that I provided above in the question uses System.Management.Automation.  I solved the issue (or at least appears to be solved) by using Process running powershell.exe and passing arguments to it.

Comment: I did notice that you were using System.Management.Automation. What I was saying is that your given example was specifically using a `Runspace` instance to do its thing, when there actually exists a `Powershell` class within the same namespace that could have solved you problems. See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx)

Comment: @PhilGref  I'm sorry for the late response.  I will try that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just used Process class executing powershell.exe and passing arguments to it.  It's not the best solution.  But then again, I don't see ya'll rushing to help and providing a solution either :-)